# SonarQube - C# - Importing xunit results - No effects

Tags: sonarqube, xunit

I followed [sonarqube doc](https://docs.sonarqube.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=6389772#UnitTestExecutionResultsImport(C#,VB.NET)-xUnit) on how to import a xunit test execution report. I don't have any errors and the script runs fine. However, I don't see any unit tests within sonarQube.

Answer (score 0):

You're likely facing [a regression](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-csharp/issues/492#issuecomment-320704456). The workaround is

> simply adding `/d:sonar.cs.vscoveragexml.reportsPaths="**\*.coveragexml"` into the Additional Settings of the SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild - Begin Analysis (new) task.

Comment: 1) I'm not talking about vsts, just cli with xunit at this point 2) I don't have a coverage XML file as I don't manage to produce one with dotCover and x unit, but that's another issue (or not?)